# How to push tag to a branch in a CI?

Tags: git, gitlab, bitrise

I want to add a manual jobs to my Pull Request to tag my source branch when i run the manual jobs. This tag will trigger a build on my bitrise configuration.

However, when i'm trying to push my tag, i am facing this issue.
NB: The branch i'm trying to push my tag to is NOT protected.

```
$ git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
Switched to a new branch 'feature/gitlab-ci'
Branch feature/gitlab-ci set up to track remote branch feature/gitlab-ci from origin.
$ git tag build-bitrise
$ git push --tags
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/my-app/my-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My job is doing so :

```
    - git remote show origin
    - git fetch
    - git checkout $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - git tag build-bitrise
    - git push --tags
```

In my "before_scripts" step, i do :

```
before_script:
    # Install ssh-agent through openssh-client if not present
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -qy && apt-get install openssh-client -qqy )'
    # Add the private key to this user
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY") && mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    # Config git to avoid first usage questions. Set the identity
    - git config --global user.email "my-secret-email@gmail.com" && git config --global user.name "Louis Lecocq"
```

Where SSH_PRIVATE_KEY is a variable that is a copy/paste of my GITLAB profile in the ENV.

Thanks for reading and your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your current method is not working because it is still using `https` rather than `ssh` for doing the `git tag` as per the error message, so isn't using your `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/my-app/my-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

You might be able to get this working (untested) by updating the `git remote` manually before you do `git push --tags`, ie with:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:my-group/my-app/my-app
```

---

An alternative to using an `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is to use an API key. You can create an personal access token with API access from https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens, and then add the key to the `CI/CD Variables` as `API_KEY` for example.

Then in your script section, you can have something similar to:

```
script:
    - # something to do before pushing the tag
      # sometimes the remote might already exist (if using the same runner), let's just remove it and don't fail
    - git remote remove https-origin || true
      # add new https-origin remote which uses the API_KEY
    - git remote add https-origin https://gitlab-ci-token:${API_KEY}@gitlab.com/my-group/my-app.git
      # tag your build
    - git tag build-bitrise
      # push only the build-bitrise tag using the https-origin ref, and skip CI build
    - git push https-origin -o ci.skip refs/tags/build-bitrise
```

NB, would recommend using a bot account for the API_KEY, otherwise the API_KEY would have the same permissions as your user, and could be leaked by other Maintainers who would be able to see the key in CI/CD Variables, etc.

Comment: Thank you Rekovni. Indeed, i ended up trying with SSH_PRIVATE_KEY + a personal access token and setting manually
git remote set-url origin "https://gitlab-ci-token:$GITLAB_TOKEN@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git"

However, instead of using a personal access token, can i use a deploy token from the gitlab project itself ?

Comment: I don't believe so, as [deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/), do not have the `write_repository` permissions, only `read_repository`