# Automatic code merging using gitlab-ci.yml pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

My goal is to create Gitlab yml file in order to automatically merge code from **release** to **master** branch which will be run on a schedule (once a week)

Here is my **.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
image: "python:3.8"
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

Build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - <some code here>

Test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - <some code here>

job:on-schedule:
  stage: release
  only:
    - schedules
  script:
    - git config --global user.email myEmail@gmail.com
    - git config --global user.name "myUserName"
    - git checkout release
    - git checkout master
    - git merge release
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'release' did not match any file(s) known to git
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

. I'd appreciate it if you have any ideas on how to fix that.

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you for your comment, I've added my error log information

Answer (score 0):

By default, gitlab-ci does a [shallow clone](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/#shallow-cloning), and so the error you're seeing of:

```
error: pathspec 'release' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

is accurate because the `release` branch does not exist locally on the runner.

To resolve this, you can just update the lines to:

```
    - git checkout origin/release
    - git checkout origin/master
```

which will pull the latest branches from the repository directly instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But how to push these changes to a remote repo using .gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857051/how-to-push-tag-to-a-branch-in-a-ci/64896748 for a rough idea (should handle authentication).